# How to impute data from one dataframe to another in r

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have two data frames df1 and df2

```
df1= data.frame( ts = c('2020-01-15', '2020-01-16' , '2020-01-17', '2020-01-20', '2020-01-22','2020- 
                         01-24','2020-01-27','2020-01-30','2020-01-31'),
              lla=c(12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20),
              llb=c(1,2,3,4,6,5,9,8,7),
              llc=c(0.6,1.6,2.6,3.6,4.6,5.6,6.6,7.6,8.6),
              lld=c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,154,167))

df2= data.frame( ts = c('2020-01-17','2020-01-24','2020-01-31'),
             lla=NA,llb=NA,llc=NA,lld=NA)
```

if the date of df2$ts matches df1$ts it will look back 4 days ago and impute the max value of every column in df2.

For example:

the 1st value of df2$ts is "2020-01-17" matches to df1$ts .. it will look back 4 days means , it will filter out the data of df1$ts between 2020-01-13 to 2020-01-17 so we get

```
#code
df1[(as.Date(df1$ts)>= (as.Date(df2[1,1])-2)) &
   (as.Date(df1$ts)<= (as.Date(df2[1,1]))),]
#i am writing this in a loop so that it would iterate over every date of df2

df1= data.frame( ts = c('2020-01-15', '2020-01-16' , '2020-01-17'),
              lla=c(12,13,14),
              llb=c(1,2,3),
              llc=c(0.6,1.6,2.6),
              lld=c(10,11,12))
```

So now we have to get the max of every column which we would achieve with this code

```
#would return the maximum of every column
apply(ohlc[(as.Date(ohlc$ts)>= (as.Date(cls[1,1])-2)) &
  (as.Date(ohlc$ts)<= (as.Date(cls[1,1]))),],2,max)
```

But I don't know how to input this data in df2 for matching date i.e "2020-01-17" and so on for other dates of df2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
libray(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(ts=as.Date(ts))
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(ts=as.Date(ts))

my_function <- function(x,df){
      df %>% filter(ts >= (x$ts-3) &  ts <= x$ts) %>%
            mutate(ts=x$ts) %>%
            summarise(across(.cols = lla:lld, .fns = max)) %>%
            mutate(ts=x$ts)}

lapply(split(df2,df2$ts),my_function,df=df1) %>% do.call(rbind,.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `roll` after creating a new column 4 days back

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
# // convert columns to Date class
df1$ts <- as.Date(df1$ts)
df2$ts <- as.Date(df2$ts)
nm1 <- names(df2)[-1]
# // change the type of NA columns from logical to numeric
setDT(df2)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = nm1]

# // subtract 4 days from ts to create ts1
setDT(df1)[, ts1 := ts %m-% days(4)]

# do a rolling join while getting the `max` for each column
df2[df1, (nm1) := lapply(mget(paste0("i.", nm1)), max), 
           on = .(ts = ts1), roll = -Inf, by = .EACHI]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach using `runner`

```r
df1$ts <- as.Date(df1$ts)
df2$ts <- as.Date(df2$ts)

library(runner)
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(across(!ts, ~max_run(x = df1[[cur_column()]],
                              k = 4,
                              idx = df1$ts,
                              at = cur_data()[[1]])))

#>           ts lla llb llc lld
#> 1 2020-01-17  14   3 2.6  12
#> 2 2020-01-24  17   6 5.6  15
#> 3 2020-01-31  20   8 8.6 167
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>